# Jest selenium automate testing using docker compose

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose, jestjs

I am trying to run this demo project [here](https://github.com/mathieux51/jest-selenium) with docker compose. It does not work using docker compose  but It works without any problem when run with manually.

After days of try I am still not able to figure out what are the right steps?

Any help would be appreciated with given example.

Comment: Can you share your Docker files?

Comment: Here is the [link](https://gist.github.com/jaihan/a55d546cbdc07f0c44f2961ce363e52f)  to view my docker and docker-compose file.

Comment: Although I'm unable to run the project either locally or via Docker, I get the same output in both the places. The only difference was that I get a warning in Docker because it's running Alpine: `npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})`